# Je veux changer la couleur sur flutter mais je suis bloqué

Tags: flutter

```
child: TextButton(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: const Text(
                      'Dark',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        darkMode = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

The named parameter 'color' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'color'.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses English as its primary language.

Comment: @MyCar, [please don't translate other users' posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/354577): "Non-English posts should not normally be translated into English by anyone other than the original poster (OP)… The OP needs to be able to respond to feedback provided in English (via comments, answers, or Help Center content). Translating a post for a non-English speaker sets them, and anyone participating on the post, up for a poor experience, due to the OP not being able to follow and respond to comments, understand answers, or get assistance from the Help Center."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextButton` did not have color as a parameter, it is necessary to add the *color property* only in style.

```
child: TextButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      'Dark',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        darkMode = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: Stack Overflow uses English as its primary language.

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't specific to what color you actually want to change so :

if you want to change the Ink ( ripples ) add this as a property to `TextButton`

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.red,
          ),
```

if you want to change the background color use this :

```
 style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
```

but consider using `ElevatedButton` also, if you want a button with background color

Hope this help